How to preserve underscores in enum values when generating C# client code using OpenAPI Generator?
I am generating client code using the OpenAPI CSharp Generator. In my OpenAPI.json file, the enums are defined in uppercase with underscores (e.g., ENUM_VALUE). However, when the client is generated, the underscores are removed from the enum values. I found solutions for other generators but couldn't locate any specific configuration for C#.
How can I ensure that the generated enum values preserve the underscores as defined in the OpenAPI.json file?
